# Gradle extension as NamedDomainObjectContainer of Closure

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to build a Gradle plugin that would allow the following:

```
myPluginConfig {
    something1 {
        // this is a closure
    }
    somethingElse {
        // this is another closure
    }
    // more closures here
}
```

To achieve this I'm fairly certain I need to use a `NamedDomainObjectContainer` to wrap a `Closure` collection, so I've set up the following plugin:

```
class SwitchDependenciesPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // add the extension
        project.getExtensions().myPluginConfig = project.container(Closure)
        // read the current configuration
        NamedDomainObjectContainer<Closure> config = project.myPluginConfig
        // test it out, always returns []
        System.out.println(config)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, do I need to use `project.extensions.create` instead? If so, how?

**EDIT**: my use case consists in adding dependencies according to some variables defined in the project hierarchy. For example, the following configuration would add the `red` project if the variable `red` is defined on `project.ext`, or `gson` otherwise:

```
myPluginConfig {
    redTrue {
        compile project(':red')
    }
    redFalse {
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    }
    greenTrue {
        compile project(':green')
    }
}
```

For this use case I need to have dynamic names for `myPluginConfig`, and therefore either a `Map` or a `NamedDomainObjectContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate what you try to model here? I think you have two options. One is to use NamedDomainObjectContainer. Here you need a class that represents "something". Have a look at the Gradle userguide chapter about maintaining multiple domain objects (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#N175CF) in the sample of the userguide, the "thing" is 'Book'. The build-in configuration syntax like you described above comes for free.

If you want to have a syntax like above without the need for maintaining multiple domain objects, you can simply add a method that takes a Closure as a parameter to your Extension class:

```
void somethingToConfigure(Closure) {
}
```

Comment: That example is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, only instead of `Book`s I need to have `Closure`s, as I then need to pass them to `project.dependencies`.

Comment: This does not work directly for `Closure` as Closure does not implement the `Named` interface nor has a `name` property.

Comment: So how can I make it work? In other words, how does Gradle do this with 'dependencies'?

Comment: `dependencies {}` in a build script is just a method with the signature `void dependencies(Closure)` on Project. the closure passed in delegates then to DependencyHandler. Can you share a bit more information about your usecase?

Comment: I have specified the use case in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `Closure` as a type for `NamedDomainObjectContainer` simply because the type you use must have a property called `name` and a public constructor with a single String parameter.

To overcome this, you may create a wrapper around `Closure` with a `name` field added.